# Using Activator.CreateInstance() with properties

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, constructor

I have the following property in a base (abstract) class:

```
protected abstract Type TheType { get; }
```

The above property is instantiated by child classes:

```
protected override Type TheType
{
  get { return typeof (ChildClass); }
}
```

I'd like to instantiate the object in the base class:

```
var obj = (TheType) Activator.CreateInstance<TheType>();
```

Unfortunately, I get the following compilation error:

```
Error   1   'BaseClass.TheType' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
```

How may I invoke `Activator.CreateInstance()` in this scenario?

PS: I've tried changing the property to a field:

```
protected Type TheType;
```

Still I get compilation error:

```
'BaseClass.TheType' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'
```

Comment: `TheType` is a name of property, it's not name of some class you are instanitating

Comment: While @Lukazoids answer is correct, keep in mind that this way is probably providing the weekest guarantee in terms of (static) safety. Depending on your usecase a combination of generic baseclass, factory children, common interface for created instance, ... might improve overall quality. Do you mind providing more details?

Answer (score 4):

`TheType` is a property which returns returns a `Type`, it is not a `Type` itself.

Use the [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of the [`Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd(v=vs.110).aspx) method, i.e.

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(TheType);
```

Because you do not know which `Type` `TheType` will return, you will be unable to cast it to a specific type at runtime.